# Captcha verification redirects to CAPTCHA page

Tags: bug, captcha

On a number of Stack Exchange sites (including meta.stackexchange.com and rpg.stackexchange.com) I'm getting stuck in a loop proving I'm a human when I try to issue a search.

I click the box (a text-based [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) may or may not appear), the blue circle spins, the green tick appears, and then I'm redirected... to the same human verification page.

Other Stack Exchange sites seem to work fine (stackoverflow.com, for example).

Comment: I'm getting this right now on crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? I'm getting that on a machine where I use HTTPS Everywhere (because I'm frequently using untrusted networks).

Comment: @Gilles Ah! I do use HTTPS Everywhere on this machine (where I've been having the problem); I'd forgotten that. And yes, it does seem to go away when I switch it off.