# Cannot pass the captcha on my smartphone (Android)

Tags: bug, mobile-web, captcha

I have several problems when searching Stack Overflow on my smartphone (I've tried both the mobile and desktop version of the site, it's the same):

1. I get a captcha *everytime* I do a search;
2. tapping inside the box *never* works - I always have to take the picture test;
3. and to top it all, when I pick the right pictures *I am redirected to another captcha page* !

The process is completely broken on my phone, does anyone else have this?

Edit: Someone else seems to have a similar problem: [Captcha verification redirects to CAPTCHA page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251511/captcha-verification-redirects-to-captcha-page).

Comment: If you're not signed in, you will get a captcha when you search. Are you signed in?

Comment: So, it's keep looping you in captcha? Have you tried login in

Comment: No I'm not logged in when I browse on my smartphone. But still there is no reason why it shouldn't work :-/

Comment: @kevinlelo did yo read the comment on the similar question? Try that solution and if it works

Comment: @HackerKarma No it doesn't seem to be the same problem

Comment: Are you using Tor (Orweb for Android)?  It gives me a captcha when I try to access SE sites.

Comment: @Jacob Swanson No I'm using Chrome developer.

Comment: @kevinlelo have you tried disabling Developer tools?

Comment: @JacobSwanson I'm talking about the android version of Chrome developer so there are no tools. It's just an alpha release of the browser