# Captcha verification doesn't advance once completed

Tags: bug, captcha

I'm trying to post a Q&A on Android Enthusiasts, and despite being logged in, I'm being forced to solve a Captcha.

That's not the main problem though. The problem is it doesn't actually let me advance once I've completed the captcha. Three times now I sat through solving a Captcha, and each time it just closes the dialog and brings me back to the first screen with the "I am not a robot" button. When I click it again, it reopens the dialog and forces me to do it again.

I don't think I'm willing to sacrifice any more brain cells sitting through those awful tests, so I'm just going to use the app, but I thought I'd post that something screwy is going on with the Captcha

Android, Dolphin Browser.

Comment: And it didn't ask me to do a captcha to post this.

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251511/323179) the same problem?

Comment: @Laurel Seems similar, although I never get a free check, and it isn't the lovely text-based captcha.

Comment: Whoops. *green check

Comment: @Carcigenicate A half hour ago I was asked to check the box, it was accepted immediately. (Location North America). Firefox on Android.

Comment: @Rob I'm on Government WiFi, so it may have appeared sketchy for some reason; although I thought being logged in would be verification enough.