# Allow bypassing CAPTCHA based on reputation or network experience

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I was trying to post a question on Android Enthusiasts earlier on my (government) work WiFi, and was put through a [slightly painful experience involving captcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329263/300788).

This got me thinking, why am I even suspicious? Yes, I'm on my non-home WiFi so there may be suspicious traffic related to other people using the internet here, but I'm logged in to my account on the Stack Exchange Network. I have close to 30k rep across the Network, have been a member for some 5 years, and AFAIK, don't have any major strikes against my account.

Why are "established users" required to complete captcha? I would think that any instance of someone running amok would be fringe at best and easily handled on a case-by-case basis.

Can experience on the site be taken into consideration when prompting someone for a captcha?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear/2293#2293

Comment: If you have at least 200 reputation and have solved one in the last five minutes, you won't have to solve one again.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog It's extraordinarily unlikely that I'd ever run into such a case though; it's rare for me to get a captcha in the first place. I'm not asking this because I think it's a big deal or anything. I just think that the current way it's set up is sub-optimal and  doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If the community/mods disagree with my suggestion, then ok. This certainly isn't the hill I'm willing to die on. I just thought I'd bring it up.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your post is very reasonable, and I've run into this, myself, even on my own network at home. I'm glad you "brought it up."

Comment: It's not just the possibility that *you, the established user* might be suddenly running amok - one has to consider the possibility that it's some malicious person who has stolen your credentials, or sat down at your workstation while you're still logged in.  I would guess this happens more often than we think.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was referring to compromised accounts when I mentioned "someone running amok", although I could have made that more explicit. And it does seem to be a dupe, but I disagree with the reasoning. Are high activity accounts really compromised at a rate that justifies safety measures? Regardless, I'll accept that.